# Ordering by a metadata subfield in Wordpress?

Tags: query, order

```
$wpQuery = new \WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'category_name' => 'products',
    'lang' => bgCurrentLangIso(),
    'meta_key' => 'hgcf',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));



$metadata = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hgcf', true);
$currentYear = $metadata['hg-aw-year'];
```

Ok, so I want to query by hg-aw-year, but the problem is that it's a metadata inside hgcf, how do you order by a metadata subfield? The above works, but doesn't give me the results I want. It creates duplicate posts and I am wondering if it's at all possible to query by hg-aw-year.

Comment: Define "subfield".

Comment: hgcf is an array and the value is stored inside the key 'hg-aw-year', so hgcf is an array of key value pair.

Comment: Then you cannot sort by it. You'd have to sort in your PHP, or re-structure your meta in the DB.

Comment: Yeah, I actually made an associative array instead and sorted that instead of using WPQUERY.